# Constructors fields max number java

Tags: java, printing, constructor, max, field

I made a program that is a simulation of a hotel with java and in this program you make Rooms as constructors and I want to print the max of 2 constructors fields (which is more expensive). I know how to make the method that returns the difference of the 2 prices but I don't know how to print which is the most expensive... here's my code.

Main Class

```
    String RoomNumber, Category, View;
    int NumberOfBeds;
    double Price;

    Room RoomA = new Room("C101",2,"Standard","Sea",95.89);



    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give room number \n");
    RoomNumber=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Give number of beds \n");
    NumberOfBeds=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Give category \n");
    Category=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Give view \n");
    View=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Give price \n");
    Price=sc.nextDouble();

    Room RoomB = new Room(RoomNumber, NumberOfBeds, Category, View, Price);
    System.out.println(RoomA.toString());
    System.out.println(RoomB.toString());
    System.out.println(""); //this is the part I am struggling
```

and this is my room class

```
public String RoomNumber;
public int NumberOfBeds;
private String Category;
private String View;
private double Price;

     public Room(String RoomNumber, int NumberOfBeds, String Category, String View, double Price){
    RoomNumber = this.RoomNumber;
    NumberOfBeds = this.NumberOfBeds;
    Category = this.Category;
    View = this.View;
    Price = this.Price;
}


   public void setRoomNumber(String roomnumber){
    this.RoomNumber = roomnumber;
}
public String getRoomNumber(){
    return this.RoomNumber;
}

public void setNumberOfBeds(int numberofbeds){
    this.NumberOfBeds = numberofbeds;
}
public int getNumberOfBeds(){
    return this.NumberOfBeds;
}

public void setCategory(String category){
    this.Category = category;
}
public String getCategory(){
    return this.Category;
}

public void setView(String view){
    this.View = view;
}
public String getView(){
    return this.View;
}

public void setPrice(double price){
    this.Price = price;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return this.Price;
}


public double getPriceDifference(double double1, double double2){
    if (double1 > double2){

        return double1-double2;  //and i know that here is the part i must add something
    }else{
        return double2-double1;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Room number:" + this.RoomNumber + ",\n "
            + "Number of beds:" + this.NumberOfBeds + ",\n " + "Category:"
            + this.Category + ",\n " + "View:" + this.View + ",\n " + "Price:" + this.Price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use methods outside of room to calculate price difference, as it is business logic. Room shuold only be a data holder. In future it would be easyer to expand the operation.

```
private static Room moreExpensiveRoom(Room room1, Room room2){
   return room1.getPrice() > room2.getPrice()? room1 : room2;
}
```

For checking price difference you can use [Math.abs()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_abs.htm) method:

```
private static double priceDifference(Room room1, Room room2){
   return Math.abs(room1.getPrice()- room2.getPrice());
}
```

When you would like to compare more than two rooms, than you need to create a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)  and use to sort Room list, then take the one with biggest price. Or use streams with [max()](http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-stream-findAny-findFirst-limit-max-min-example)

**And lastly**: please read about variable naming conventions in java, all non-static  variables should start with lowerCase, CamelCase is reserved for class names only.

Comment: [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) for classes etc., [lowerCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for methods, variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Room getMostExpensive(ArrayList<Room> rooms) {
    double max = 0d;
    Room room = null;
    for (Room room1 : rooms) {
        if (max < room1.getPrice()) {
            max = room1.getPrice();
            room = room1;
        }
    }
    return room;
}
```

Place this in your main class and add a list of all the rooms as a parameter when calling the method